# Получить Drawable by id из Static метода?

Tags: android, android-drawable, context

Пишу `Static` метод, который по параметру возвращает необходимый `Drawable`. Как мне получить `Drawable` по `id` не получая `Context`? Т.е. получая только `String`?

```
public static Drawable getDrawableByString(Context context, String color) {
    Drawable retDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.round_transparent);
        switch (color) {
            case "RED":
                retDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.round_darkred);
                break;
            case "BLUE":
                retDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.round_blue);
                break;
    }
    return retDrawable;
}
```

Comment: А если так: `Drawable retDrawable = Resources.getSystem().getDrawable(R.drawable.round_transparent)`? Но вообще это нехорошо.

Comment: Как вариант - получайте контекст из синглтона класса Application. Так можно будет убрать аргумент и получать контекст в самом методе

Comment: вы все равно без контекста не сможете с этим Drawable ничего сделать. То есть вывести на экран вы его сможете только при помощи контекста. Так что я не вижу смысла пытаться его убирать.